# Making a HighScore List in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I made a jeopardy game in VB.Net

I know I am missing some codes but I don't know what should I use.

I need to save in a txt file and load it to a listbox.

here is my code:

```
Private Sub SummaryMenu_Load (sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    highscoreFile = FreeFile()

    FileOpen(highscoreFile,
                 "jeeperdeyData.txt",
                 OpenMode.Input)

    FileClose()

    If totalScore > highscoreFile Then

        highscore = totalScore

        FileOpen(highscoreFile,
                 "jeeperdeyData.txt",
                 OpenMode.Output)

        WriteLine(highscoreFile, username & "     " & highscore)

        FileClose(highscoreFile)

    End If

End Sub
```

i have the variables in modules

'files

```
Public highscoreFile As Integer
```

Thanks

Comment: `FreeFile()`, `FileOpen()`, and `FileClose()` exist only for backwards compatibility with older pre-.Net versions of VB, and should not be used for new developement.

Answer (score 0):

This replicates the work from the existing method with APIs that are actually under active use, though it seems odd to do all of this in a method named "SummaryMenu_Load()":

```
Private Class ScoreData
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Score as Integer

    Public Shared Function FromFileLine(line As String) As ScoreData
         Dim data = line.Split(vbTab)
         Return New ScoreData With {Name = data(0), Score = Integer.Parse(data(1))}
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function ToString()
        Return $"{Name}{vbTab}{Score}"
    End Function

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property MaxScores As Integer = 10
End Class

Private Sub SummaryMenu_Load (sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    var scores = File.ReadLines("jeeperdeyData.txt").
             Select(AddressOf ScoreData.FromFileLine).
             OrderByDescending(Function(s) s.Score).
             ToList()
    
    If scores.Count < ScoreData.MaxScores Then 
        scores.Add(new ScoreData With {Name = username, Score = highscore})
    Else

        Dim i As Integer = 0
        While i < scores.Count AndAlso highscore <= scores(i).Score
             i++ 
        End While

        If i < scores.Count Then 'Greater than at least one existing entry
            Dim current As ScoreData = scores(i)
            scores(i) = New ScoreData With {Name = username, Score = highscore}
            i+=1
            While i < scores.Count 
                Dim temp As ScoreData = scores(i)
                scores(i) = current
                current = temp
                i+=1
            End While
        End If
    End IF

    File.WriteAllLines("jeeperdeyData.txt", scores.Select(Function(s) s.ToString()))
End Sub
```